# Creating an SPN cipher from ChaCha20 or Salsa20's double round function

Tags: symmetric, salsa20, chacha

Given that ChaCha20's building blocks have been also used to construct a hash function, can the double round function from either ChaCha20 or Salsa20 be used to construct a secure SP-network cipher?

The double round function serves as the permutation function and 512-bit round keys are XORed with the permuted result for each round:

- $F: \{0,1\}^{512} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{512}$ is the double round function.
- $G: \{0,1\}^{512} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{512}$ is the inverse of $F$.
- $R(rk, x)=F(x) \oplus rk$ is a single encryption round.
- $S(rk, y)=G(y \oplus rk)$ is a single decryption round.

Comment: If you have one crypto operation, you can basically roll any other crypto operation. It might not necessarily be efficient to do so though.

Comment: You would need to be careful with the key schedule to prevent rotational cryptanalysis.